# Selenium devtool network Java package

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, package

Where can I get the Selenium devtool network related Java packages?

I'm getting the following errors:

```
error: package org.openqa.selenium.devtools.network does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.network.Network;

error: package org.openqa.selenium.devtools.network.model does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.network.model.Headers;
```

and I was having a hard time fixing it.

From these two urls,

- https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-devtools/4.0.0-alpha-5/source-code/org/openqa/selenium/devtools/network/model/Headers.java
- https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-devtools/4.0.0-alpha-5/source-code/org/openqa/selenium/devtools/network/Network.java

It seems they both comes from:

```json
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-devtools</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-alpha-5</version>
</dependency>
```

Is it that I have to install this *specific* and *old* version? As I got the latest 4.0.0-rc-1 in `target/dependency/selenium-devtools-4.0.0-rc-1.jar`, but I'm still getting the above compilation errors.

How to fix them please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import devtools packages as well as `Netowrk` like

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.HasDevTools;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v118.browser.Browser;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v118.network.Network;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v118.network.model.Headers;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v118.performance.Performance;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v118.performance.model.Metric;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v118.runtime.Runtime;
```

with `pom.xml` artifact declaration

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

See https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/cdp_api/

Its example on Github: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/blob/trunk//examples/java/src/test/java/dev/selenium/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/CdpApiTest.java#L24-L31